# How to load a dropdown list box from Mysql database using C# asp.net?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I want to load the dropdown list box with a column of a table from Mysql in asp.net with C#.

Comment: 2 upvotes in 37 seconds for this question?

Comment: @SonerGönül and 3 favs :P

Comment: Yes Nice question 4 answers in just 5 min..

Comment: -1, "does not show any research effort"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So right now you've noted that you just want to load a single field. That's what the following code would do. It will select a single field, from a single table, and bind it to the combo box.

```
using (MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    c.Open();

    var sql = "SELECT field_name FROM table_name";
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, c))
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

        comboBox.ValueMember = "field_name";
        comboBox.DisplayMember = "field_name";
        comboBox.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

However, I think the more general use of it might be something like this:

```
using (MySqlConnection c = new MySqlConnection(connString))
{
    c.Open();

    var sql = "SELECT key_field, display_field FROM table_name";
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, c))
    {
        var dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

        comboBox.ValueMember = "key_field";
        comboBox.DisplayMember = "display_field";
        comboBox.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Here you're listing data and have both a `key_field` and a `display_field`. The importance of that is generally combo boxes are used for lookup type data. Either way, when you wanted to get the value of the combo box, use the `SelectedValue` member.

```
comboBox.SelectedValue
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but can i get the same in C# asp.net

Comment: @user2959767: The provided code is already in C#...

Comment: @David :) I ... I just lol'd :)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Stackoverflow:)

Please refer below code snippet  for your requiremrnt:

```
var connectionString = "connection string goes here";
    using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        var query = "SELECT Id FROM Customers";
        using (var command = new MySqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                //Iterate through the rows and add it to the combobox's items
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    CustomerIdComboBox.Items.Add(reader.GetString("Id"));    
                }
            }    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit Vyas for your fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

```
string str="Select km from tablename;
            SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(str,connection object);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ad.Fill(ds);

            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                Textbox1.Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
            }
```